# Disable address bar in IOS when using Web@Work browser

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, browser, web

I create website for customer, but he want to using webs@work to using my website on ios. For security he require to disable an address bar of browser , I tried to used javascript and is worked on safari but on web@work it wasn't,

anyone can't give me some sollution to solved please.

webs@work : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mobileiron-web-work/id596170970?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no such feature in the Web@work browser.
To access a website which is "behind" a MobileIron infrastructure you have to develop a "simple" fullscreen browser app which is wrapped with the MobileIron App wrapper or which includes the MobileIron AppConnect SDK. In MobileIron you can define a configuration for that app to connect to the intranet ressource.

Answer (score 0):

You can push a webclip from MobileIron core or cloud with your URL prefixed with W@W scheme.
You could use "mibrowserf://" and "mibrowsersf://" schemes to open HTTP and HTTPS links in iOS W@W in a full screen mode.